# ClickHouse ReplacingMergeTree

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to understand how is working the `ReplacingMergeTree` engine.

I have the following table configured with such engine.

`┌─brand─┬─country─┬─id─────┬────updated─┬─version─┐
│ IM    │ FR      │      1 │ 2017-09-29 │       2 │
│ IM    │ FR      │      2 │ 2017-09-29 │       0 │
│ IM    │ FR      │      3 │ 2017-09-29 │       1 │
└───────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────┘`

At this point everything is ok.

Then I execute the following `INSERT`.

`INSERT INTO table(brand, country, id, updated, version) VALUES ('IM', 'FR', 1, '2017-10-29', 3);`

As expected, there are 2 rows with id `1`:

`┌─brand─┬─country─┬─id─────┬────updated─┬─version─┐
│ IM    │ FR      │      1 │ 2017-09-29 │       2 │
│ IM    │ FR      │      2 │ 2017-09-29 │       0 │
│ IM    │ FR      │      3 │ 2017-09-29 │       1 │
└───────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────┘
┌─brand─┬─country─┬─id─────┬────updated─┬─version─┐
│ IM    │ FR      │      1 │ 2017-10-29 │       3 │
└───────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────┘`

As the primary key for this table is `(brand, country, id)`, I would expect that a merge on this table would replace the row with id=1 having the lower version 2.

Triggering a merge with `OPTIMIZE TABLE table` to check that, it seems that it didn't work in this way, and that both rows are surprisingly kept.

`┌─brand─┬─country─┬─id─────┬────updated─┬─version─┐
│ IM    │ FR      │      1 │ 2017-10-29 │       3 │
└───────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────┘
┌─brand─┬─country─┬─id─────┬────updated─┬─version─┐
│ IM    │ FR      │      1 │ 2017-09-29 │       2 │
│ IM    │ FR      │      2 │ 2017-09-29 │       0 │
│ IM    │ FR      │      3 │ 2017-09-29 │       1 │
└───────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────┘`

Comment: Can you try this `OPTIMIZE TABLE table FINAL`? Also, show us create table statement.

Comment: The sort key is used for deduplication. How the primary key is defined is irrelevant. Make sure you have order by (brand,country,id).

Answer (score 1):

Logically it should work as you describe. 
Probably a problem with `version` column name? If you do not specify it during table definition, it is called `_part_index`?

Can you provide your `show create table`?

There are tests for ReplacingMergeTree https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/012c5f1079e7a2605e872eb223b9c5dcd065880e/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00325_replacing_merge_tree.sql.disabled

Documentation: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/replacingmergetree.html

Comment: No it's called `version` an unsigned integer

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness of rows is determined by the `ORDER BY` table section, not `PRIMARY` KEY.
See document [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/)